# How to choose a browser version in web component tester?

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, web-component-tester

Does wct config allow for choosing a specific version of Chrome, like Chrome 34?

It seems to install chrome at the beginning every time I run wtc.

Answer (score 3):

Following [Polymer Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests), it's possible to run tests choosing a browser installed on your computer. If you have Chrome 34 version and you execute `test -l chrome`, tests will run with this version. If you don't have Chrome 34, it's no possible.

All supported browsers to run tests are *aurora*, *canary*, *chrome*, *firefox* and *ie*.

> Web Component Tester automatically finds all of the browsers installed
>   on your system and runs your tests against each one.  If you wanted to
>   run your tests against a single browser, say Google Chrome, you could
>   polymer `test -l chrome`.